# Custom routes rendering with Html.BeginRouteForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, html.beginform

I'm using custom route mapping in following way:

```
    context.MapRoute(
        "CustomRoute",
        "Area/{controller}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Task", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { id = @"\d+", httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
    );
```

With above route I'm going to skip action name, pass parameter via slash `/`, so I expect to have URL in following way: 
`domain.com/Area/Task/982`

It works good by entering URL manually. Now trying to do the same via `@Html.BeginRouteForm` helper:

```
    @using (Html.BeginRouteForm("CustomRoute", new { id = Model.ID }, FormMethod.Get))
    {
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ID)
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit">Get data</button>
    }
```

Submitting form it is rendering url in a way:  `domain.com/Area/Task?ID=982`

What is missing above? How can I achieve desired custom route?

Comment: You have a route value for  a property named `id` which will be the original value of the model. But then you have a textbox for the same route parameter and its the value of the textbox which will be used. but a browser has no knowledge of routes (server side code) so the value is added as a query string. Your `new { id = Model.ID }` is pointless and should be removed. And if your want `../Area/Task/982` then you need javascript

Comment: Removing `new { id = Model.ID }` giving me exactly same result. Agree, using javascript I can generate any URL. Still trying to understand why custom route is not considered by the form.

Comment: Because a browser does not know anything about your routes (that is server side code). A form that makes a GET will always add the values of its inputs as query string values.

Comment: Ok. Clear, it makes sense.